# SmartThreadPool how to add values in the pool and run multiple threads for reading from one pool

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I am trying to implement SmartThreadPool like this one: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7933/Smart-Thread-Pool

But the problem is that I want to have a pool and I will constatnly added some values in this pool. When a process which calculate values will be finished, it will get new value from the pool for doing the job. I want to have 5 threads for calculating values from pool so that everything can work async. When job is finished, it will take new value from pool.

But i am having a problem how to implement that with Smart Thread Pool. Result method always block next execution and waits that is finished. And how to add values to already existing pool?

Is this even possible with smart thread pool or how to start?

Comment: Why not use a concurrent producer/consumer collection where values are added by some external source, and each of the 5 threads will dequeue a value when it's ready to process another item.

Comment: [ConcurrentQueue<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx) seems like a good solution to me! Also, could you give us a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)?

Comment: So solution with ConcurrentQueue is better then Tasks?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this problem is to use a [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) wrapped in a [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx). Use this resulting object and enqueue values to it from wherever they come from.  Then create 5 Tasks that run your processing method in a loop.  Everytime a thread is done processing an item it attempts to dequeue another item from the collection.  If the queue is empty it will block until a new value is added, or AddingComplete() is called on the BlockingCollection.

```
// create a blocking collection
// the constructor will take an IProducerConsumerCollection
// or it will use a ConcurrentQueue<T> by default if none is provided
var blockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<String>();

// generate items and add them to the collection
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        blockingCollection.Add("value" + i);
    }
    // mark adding as complete so the foreach loops
    // below will exit when the collection is empty
    blockingCollection.AddingComplete();
});

// create worker 1 to process items
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    foreach (string value in blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable()) {
        Console.WriteLine("Worker 1: " + value);
    }               
});

// create worker N to process items
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    foreach (string value in blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable()) {
        Console.WriteLine("Worker N: " + value);
    }               
});
```

Here is a good page to read more about it and see additional examples: http://www.codethinked.com/blockingcollection-and-iproducerconsumercollection